# Custom Compare function for for a priority_queue of struct pointers

Tags: c++, struct, priority-queue

I have a `priority_queue` of struct pointers and I want to get some "active" node with the least "val" value.  This is what I found but it doesn't care about nodes' activity but just gives the element with least value.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


struct node{
    long long val;
    bool active;
};

struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(const node *a,const node *b)const
    {
        if(a->active == b->active)
            return (a->val) > (b->val);
        if(a->active)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
};

typedef priority_queue<node*, vector<node*> ,Compare > PQ;

int main()
{
    PQ q;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        node* nd=new node;
        nd->val = x;
        nd->active = 1;
        q.push(nd);
    }
    node* first =q.top();
    cout << "the top element is " << (first->val) << endl;
    q.pop();
    first->active = 0;
    q.push(first);
    node* second = q.top();
    cout << "the next top element is " << (second->val) << endl;
    cout << "the activity state of the second element is " << (second->active) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:** The code works now and does care about nodes' activity

Comment: Post the code in the question.

Comment: Also show the costume

Comment: You can't change a value in a priority_queue and expect it to reorder everything

Comment: so what should I do? @Kevin

Comment: @Shahriar M As a remark, maybe you should rather have `if(a->active == b->active)`, (`==` instead of `&&`) so you could also compare two inactive nodes, instead of returning `false` if none or just `b` is active... Just a thought.

Comment: @LogicStuff thank you.You were right

Answer (score 1):

Elements in a `priority_queue` cannot be modified after being added. If you want to do this you need to `pop` the value off, modify it, and then `push` it back on.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function used with a `std::priority_queue<...>` needs to define a [*strict weak order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). Your ordering function doesn't define a strict weak order: if an object `x` is inactive (i.e. `active` is `false`) you have `Compare()(x, x) == true` but the condition `Compare()(x, x) == false` (using relational symbol: `!(x < x) == true`, i.e., `x` isn't smaller than `x`) had to hold.

When the constraint on the comparison function are not met, the behavior of the `std::priority_queue<...>` is undefined.